# How to block certain IP address to access certain domain/IP via iptables in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

How to block certain IP address to access  certain domain/IP in Linux ?

I have CentOS installed on my server for virtual server purposes. I have a few virtual servers clients each one with his own IP. I need to block their IP to access certain domain.

I know this iptables rules totally blocks access to certain IP but I only need to limit the access only to a few clients, so this one block total access :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.123.123 -j DROP
```

I need one rule that will mention what IP would be blocked from access 123.123.123.123

Comment: Are you looking also to restrict the *source* address affected?  Have you tried `iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.1.1.0/28 -d 192.168.3.3 -j DROP`?

Comment: I need to block IP 123.123.123 to access 111.111.111.111, actually I need to block some IP from my network to access certain website.

Comment: So specify the required source address/block to be `DROP`ped with `-s`, the required destination address/block with `-d`.  Blocking destination domains can't be done reliably in `iptables`, as a very small amount of searching on SF would have told you (eg, [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/427267/how-to-allow-a-single-domain-name-with-iptables) or [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/360689/permanently-blocking-a-domain-in-iptables) ).

Comment: If you need to prevent access to some website you can also use some access rule in the webserver configuration. E.g.: for apache 2.2 you can use mod_authz rules: `order allow,deny` and `allow from all` `deny from 123.123.123.123`. Other webserver has similar ways to block ip from accessing a website without having to fiddle with low-level tool. The advantage is that  you can prevent access to a single website on a shared host.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-s` | `--source` address parameter to filter on the source address.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -s a.b.c.d  -d w.x.y.z -j DROP
```